# Angular filter for credit card with replacement

Tags: angularjs, input, filter, formatting

Is there a simple way to show data in credit card input, with angular1, like:

> #### - #### - #### - #### ?

Replace numbers with any symbols and add  "-" between every 4 numbers

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5hw9nd0g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do an input mask, you should use [Angular UI-Mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask)

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own directive or use this one: https://github.com/OutlawAndy/angular-card-input

Comment: It's good, but how to replace numbers with symbols? type="password" will replace all symbols, even hyphens

Comment: What symbols? If you want to have #### - #### - #### - #### on the beginning, just put it as placeholder <input placeholder="#### - #### - #### - ####"/>